# Nestjs call request scoped service without request

Tags: nestjs

After adding a request scoped service to an existing codebase, many of the seeder functions calling services directly return `undefined` for request scoped services (as no HTTP request has actually been sent).

How can I "seed" a request instance so it's available and can be resolved as a dependency in the service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following utility function will seed a request and return an ID for usage:

```js
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common'
import { ContextIdFactory } from '@nestjs/core'

/**
 * Seeds a request and returns the context ID
 * for referencing (e.g. for `NestApplication.resolve()`).
 *
 * Request scoped services rely on a HTTP request
 * to be made to be instantiated, and
 * seeders do not fire HTTP requests to
 * generate context.
 */
export const seedRequest = <T extends {}>(app: INestApplication, req: T) => {
  const contextId = ContextIdFactory.create()
  app.registerRequestByContextId(req, contextId)

  return {
    contextId,
  }
}
```

Use like so:

```js
const app: INestApplication

// initialise app, etc...

const contextId = seedRequest(app, {
  req: {
    user: {
      id: 'abc123',
    },
  },
})

const someService = await app.resolve(SomeService, contextId)

// use someService...
```

Comment: Awesome! To use it in other modules you can work with moduleRef which replaces `app` in this example https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#resolving-scoped-providers