# Create a request scope without a request

Tags: nestjs

I have an multitenant application that has a lot of request scoped services, where I look at the origin to see which tenant we're talking about, and which database filters to use, etc. This works fine as long as there is a request, but now I want to run a script for each of the tenants.

What I would like to do is loop through all the tenants, initialize a request scope for each tenant and run whatever needs to be run. How do I do this?

I am in the Nest context (a module's `onApplicationBootstrap`, to be specific), so I do have access to DI, just not the dependencies that depend on the request scope.

I found this post: [Nestjs call request scoped service without request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718970/nestjs-call-request-scoped-service-without-request)

But it leaves me with some questions:

- how do I get a hold of NestApplication
- it looks like the request is globally registered to the scope, doesn't that mean that after the loop is finished, the application still thinks it's in that request scope?

Comment: We have the same problem. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not